# Passing Protractor command line parameters as variable

Tags: typescript, automation, protractor

I know how to pass params as string but they don't seem to be working when it comes to variables.

Conf.ts

```
params: {
        testEnvironment: TestEnvironment.Prod,
},
```

env.ts

```
export enum TestEnvironment {
    Dev = 'dev',
    QA = 'qa',
    Prod = 'production',
}
```

command line

```
"test:smokeTestsProd": "npm run tsc && protractor tmp/config.js --suite smokeTests --parameters.testEnvironment=TestEnvironment.Dev",
```

To get this working I can use

```
"test:smokeTestsProd": "npm run tsc && protractor tmp/config.js --suite smokeTests --parameters.testEnvironment='Dev'",
```

and get this in config (just pseudo code below):

```
if(Dev) {
testEnvironment: TestEnvironment.Dev,
}
```

but this totally defeats the need of having an env.ts.

Answer (score 0):

You see the thing is you can't use the passed parameter within the config file, but it'll later become available in your spec file through `browser` object like this `console.log(browser.params.testEnvironment)` and is usually used for credentials or something that you don't need in the config.

If you intend to reuse it in the config you could do the following

```
"test:smokeTestsProd": "MY_VAR=Dev npm run tsc && protractor tmp/config.js --suite smokeTests"
```

And then this in your config

```
params: {
    testEnvironment: TestEnvironment[process.env.MY_VAR]
}
```

Note this is js code, not ts, but the logic should remain the same